# C# Access function in another Form Class

Tags: c#

i start my programm with a form called "mainWindow" in this form i have a button and this run a function that open a new form as object. my problem is i cant access a control on this object or a function on this object and i dont understand why

the first form:

```
public partial class mainWindow : Form
{
    public mainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.drawDriverGrid();
    }

    public void drawDriverGrid() 
    {
        Form driverGridForm = new driverGridView();
        driverGridForm.GetSelected();
    }
```

this is the second form

```
public partial class driverGridView : Form 
{
    public driverGridView() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int GetSelected() 
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

i cant run the GetSelected function

Comment: You declare a `Form` called driverGridForm, but your class is actually a `driverGridView`.  If you want to access members of a `driverGridView` than your instance has to be of that type.

Comment: For your future Stack Overflow usage:  Never say "I can't do X".  We know you can't do X; if you could, you wouldn't be asking the question.  Say what is happening: "When I tried I got this error BLAH BLAH BLAH on this line, and I tried debugging it like this, and here's what happened..."  In this case it is obvious what is wrong, but if it were not obvious, "I can't make it work" gives us nothing to go on to try to diagnose the problem.

Comment: You need to get an instance to the form class.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @jdweng: The use *has* an instance; read the given code.

Comment: WHile you're at it, look up standard coding conventions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/index) - class names should ideally start with a capital letter e.g. `MainWindow`, `DriverGridView`

Comment: I can almost smell his next question would be: why does that GetSelected line not run after he called driverGridForm.ShowDialog();

Comment: Is it the same instance all the time in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler must be informed (HA HA) that you intend to use a method of driverGridView. So NOT:

```
    Form driverGridForm = new driverGridView();
    driverGridForm.GetSelected();
```

By saying "Form" in the declaration of driverGridForm you are saying "I only wish to use methods of Form with this variable".

Rather, you intended to say "I wish to use methods of driverGridView with this variable", so:

```
    driverGridView driverGridForm = new driverGridView();
    driverGridForm.GetSelected();
```

Or, better:

```
    var driverGridForm = new driverGridView();
    driverGridForm.GetSelected();
```

which means "let the compiler deduce from the `new` expression what type I meant here".

Note also that C# naming conventions are that class names and namespace names and method names start with a capital, so it should be

```
    var driverGridForm = new DriverGridView();
    driverGridForm.GetSelected();
```

and it should be `namespace Test` and so on.

Comment: Could you please clarify why 
"var driverGridForm" is better than "driverGridView driverGridForm"

Comment: @DaniDev its redundant declare the type in that context.  `var` exists so that you can write `var foo = new DateTime()` instead of repeating yourself `DateTime foo = new DateTime()`

Comment: understand that part, It's "prettier". Is there any compiler or runtime benefit?

Comment: @DaniDev: The feature is useful when dealing with anonymous types because they don't have names.  However, anonymous types are now deprecated in favor of tuples in C# 7. In non-anonymous situations, `var` is just a "sugar"; it makes the code easier to read because it removes redundancy and de-emphasizes what is usually an unimportant detail. If you find that using `var` makes the code *harder* to understand then *don't use it*.